# Android chart : Multi labels on same domain

Tags: android, charts

i'm trying to implement a graph in android that uses either 2 labels on the same domain, for example:

the x-axis will have days plus temperature,and the x axis will be drawn according to temperature yes but i just want to add a days label  above or under temperature label.

something like this as x-axis example:

---

temp.  39    37    36

days   1      2       3

or i want to make the label in the upper x domain

like this:

days   1         2          3

---

temp. 37         36           34

i have tried so far the following libraries: GraphView,Android plot, achartengine

, but non could accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

I used aChartEngine and was able to produce a graph with differing axis.

```
protected void setRenderer(XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer, int[] colors, PointStyle[] styles) {
    renderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(16);
    renderer.setChartTitleTextSize(20);
    renderer.setLabelsTextSize(15);
    renderer.setLegendTextSize(15);
    renderer.setPointSize(5f);
    renderer.setYLabels(5);
    renderer.setMargins(new int[] { 30, 15, 30, 15 });
    int length = colors.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      XYSeriesRenderer r = new XYSeriesRenderer();
      r.setColor(colors[i]);
      r.setPointStyle(styles[i]);
      renderer.addSeriesRenderer(r);
    }
    renderer.setClickEnabled(true);
    renderer.setSelectableBuffer(100);
    renderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
    renderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(100, 50, 50, 50));

    renderer.setAxesColor(Color.LTGRAY);
    renderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(true);
    renderer.setPointSize(10);

    renderer.setChartTitle("Fuel Efficiency and Cost");
    //mRenderer.setXTitle("Date");

    renderer.setShowGrid(true);
    renderer.setXLabelsAlign(Align.RIGHT);
    renderer.setYLabelsAlign(Align.LEFT);


    renderer.setYTitle(cunits,0);

    renderer.setLabelsColor(Color.WHITE);
    renderer.setXLabelsColor(Color.GREEN);
    renderer.setYLabelsColor(0, colors[0]);
    renderer.setYLabelsColor(1, colors[1]);

    renderer.setYTitle(dunits, 1);
    renderer.setYAxisAlign(Align.RIGHT, 1);
    renderer.setYLabelsAlign(Align.RIGHT, 1);
  }
```

Comment: i get array out of bound error in these lines:
renderer.setYLabelsColor(1, colors[1]);

     renderer.setYTitle("dunits", 1);
     renderer.setYAxisAlign(Align.RIGHT, 1);
     renderer.setYLabelsAlign(Align.RIGHT, 1);

Comment: this is a method that is invoked from elsewhere.  I assume you would read the signature and know there is any int[] array of colors to pass in...perhaps your array is not set up?